# Is there a way to check if element was reloaded with WebDriver (java)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify an element after every update.Ex: Lowrtemperature:7.54 after some time the value changes to Lowrtemperature:3.79, and then to other value here the value is changing after some time(time varies) each time. but i need the driver to get the updated value after the change .how to get the element using selenium webdriver ,here page is not reloaded only element value is reloaded

```
public boolean waitForTextToChange(WebElement element, String currentText) {
                return !element.getText().equals(currentText);
            }


public String Lowertemperature_14_L(){
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='webForm:sensorContainer']/div[@class='tile tile23 show-all hide-tiny']/div[@class='meteo-line1']/div[1]/div[@class='icon']/div[@class='icon-label0']"));
   String currentText = element.getText();
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(waitForTextToChange(element, currentText));
   return currentText;
   }
```

Comment: `Lowrtemperature:7.54` is text? or something else?

Comment: yes it is text but only the value changes not the Lowertemperature

Comment: @Guy i am getting the error at     code:
   wait.until(waitForTextToChange(element, currentText));  error:  The method until(Predicate<WebDriver>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean) ,i addrd guava library 21 version also still i am getting the error at wait.until

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//here the first value will be ex.4.56 and then after 20 sec the value is updated to 3.67 and then so on after every 20 seconds of span (time varies some time after 8,10,6 and so on ) . i used the wait.until(Expectedconditions.stalenessOf(element)) which checked the value is updated or not ,then  we get a new updated value from the ui  and for the verification before and after updated value

```
 wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                By container = By.xpath(".//*[@id='webForm:sensorContainer']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[6]");
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(container));

                /* Read the text that appears in the XPath text control. */
                WebElement ajaxControl = driver.findElement(container);
                String ajaxTextFirstPara = ajaxControl.getText().trim();

                WebElement ele= driver.findElement(container);
                try{
                       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(ele));
                }catch(TimeoutException e){
                }

                /* Wait for the new content to appear in the xpath text control. */
                By newAjaxcontrol =  container;
                Wait<WebDriver> newwait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
                        .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
                newwait.until(ExpectedConditions
                        .visibilityOfElementLocated(newAjaxcontrol));
                WebElement undergroundTemperature_14_L_value= driver.findElement(newAjaxcontrol);
                String undergroundTemperature_14_L =undergroundTemperature_14_L_value.getText().trim();
                if(ajaxTextFirstPara!= undergroundTemperature_14_L)
                {
                    System.out.println("diffeerent");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("same");
                }
```